# How to pass cookies to Request Header using Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm looking to create an automatic download tool on Lovepik

I'm trying to pass a Cookie into the Request Header as shown below

[image: cookie]

I've searched the internet for this code, but it doesn't seem to work anymore

```
axios.post('YOUR_URL', data, {
  Cookie: 'cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;'
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this:

```
axios.post("https://example.com", "", {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Cookie: "name=value; name2=value2",
  }
});
```

but if you send request from within browser, it'll only work if the server CORS settings allow corresponding headers and requests from your origin

Comment: The server that I post the api on is not my server, how do I install CORS ?
axios.post("https://lovepik.com/download/getDownloadUrl")

I want to create an automatic download tool by passing cookies from my account to Lovepik's server to be able to download resources

Comment: you can only configure server responses' CORS headers by modifying server code. If response's CORS headers don't allow to set cookies, you won't be able send such a request from within browser - it'd be blocked. You'd be able to still fetch data from within another server or CLI/curl. So you may want to consider proxy